# how to store items in local Storage in jqueryMoblie

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, cordova, local-storage

I have 4 pages like A,B,C and D. A have fruits names, B have flowers names .4 Pages flow like this

```
 <--   
A -->C
       -->D 
B -->C
```

When i went to C through A,C have fruits names with check box,and When I Went to C through B,C have flowers names with check box.C have book Button.When we Click book button data go to D page.

What we need is When i go to  (A-->C).We select 3 fruits .Next back to B and got C.We Select 2 flowers 
Then Click on BookOrder We need to Show totla 5 items.In D page

My problem is only how to show Last selected items..

We tried The following:

in Page C

```
function imagebackRedriect( ) {
var myStuffArray =[];
 var itemName;
     $('input:checked').each(function () {
              $this = $(this);
              checkboxidforvalidation=this.id;
              itemName= $(this).closest('tr').children('td:eq(2)').text();
            myStuffArray.push([itemName]);  
            localStorage["myStuffLocalArray"] = JSON.stringify(myStuffArray);
           sessionStorage.setItem("forAllGridItems", myStuffArray);
       });
              TempItems = JSON.parse(localStorage["myStuffLocalArray"]);
        var GetallElements += sessionStorage.getItem("forAllGridItems");
    }
```

We tried When we select checkbox Data Add to JSON or Session, but when we leave and come back to C Data Will be removed.

Please guide me

Comment: are you using different names in your localstorage to store the data between A and B?

Comment: @japrescott i am not using Local-storage in A and B it's only using Page C  get :localStorage["myStuffLocalArray"] = JSON.stringify(myStuffArray);

post :TempItems = JSON.parse(localStorage["myStuffLocalArray"]);    like this

Comment: Try using the `.` notation instead of the `[...]` notation like so: `localStorage.setItem("myStuffLocalArray", JSON.stringify(myStuffArray));`...

Answer (score 0):

Try using `JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("forAllGridItems"));` in the last line when you are updating the list.

I am quite not sure why you would want to use both `sessionStorage` and `localStorage`

Which ever storage option you choose to use, it's recommended by most resources that you go with `localstorage.setItem("key", "value");`, and remember to use `JSON.stringify()` when working with any data types other than strings.

Comment: thanks for reply.We used Local_Storage like this forSetitems localStorage.setItem("item_key", ArrayBackElements); and for Getitems var gettingAllelements = localStorage.getItem("item_key");    in page C.Next We go to B to C in this time var gettingAllelements  is reinstallation so it's not save previous  data