# how to add and remove data into .JSON file

Tags: json, cordova, jquery-mobile, local-storage, session-storage

In our application we have 4 pages. Each page has 5 check boxs. If I

```
                         <--  
app flow like this page0 -->page1  -->page4   
                         -->page2  -->page4 
                         -->page3  -->paeg4
```

1. go to page 1 and select 2 items,
2. then go to page 2, and select 4 items,
3. and after that go to page 3 and select 2 items,

the total count of items selected is 11.

Now, if I now go to page 4, can I somehow store the values from all pages to *save.json* file which is located under *www* folder. I am using PhoneGap.

Comment: There are many ways to achieve that. Here is an example on how to append data on the next page from a form http://jsfiddle.net/j6btvLym/. In your case you need to store that data as you go along the pages until final submit. then check here on how to json stringify the data. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify. to write the file check the cordova site or search here on SO

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking if a PhoneGap app can write a JSON file, then the answer is yes. Use the FileSystem plugin to do so. However, if you are just saving a small amount of data, it would be far easier to use LocalStorage.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create an array , store this array in **[localStarage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)**, like got to page 1 store two value in array and update your localStorage value on every page on selection, on last page write this localStorage value in file using **[org.apache.cordova.file](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/master/doc/index.md)** plugin. I have done example, you can manage as your rquirement.

**a.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>    
    <div data-role="page" id="page_a">
        <div data-role="header" class="">
            <h3>Fruit</h3>            
        </div>
        <div role="main" id="" class="ui-content">   
            <div class="ui-field-contain">
                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="apple" id="apple" value="Apple" >
                  <label for="apple">Apple</label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="orange" id="orange" value="Orange">
                  <label for="orange">Orange</label>                    
                </fieldset>
            </div> 
            <a href="" data-ajax="false" id="btn_a" class="ui-btn ui-mini">Book Order</a>
      </div>

    </div>         
</body>
<script>

  var arr_fruit = [];
  $("#btn_a").on("click", function(event){  

     $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function(key){
       arr_fruit.push( $(this).val());
     }); 
     localStorage.setItem("arr_fruit", arr_fruit);
     location.href = "c.html";    
  })
</script>
<html>
```

**b.html**

```
<div data-role="page" id="page_b">
    <div data-role="header" class="">
        <h3>Flowers</h3>            
    </div>
    <div role="main" id="" class="ui-content">   
        <div class="ui-field-contain">
            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                <input type="checkbox" name="rose" id="rose" value="Rose" >
                <label for="rose">Rose</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="sunflower" id="sunflower" value="Sunflower">
                <label for="sunflower">Sunflower</label>                    
            </fieldset>
        </div> 
        <a href="" data-ajax="false" id="btn_b" class="ui-btn ui-mini">Book Order</a>
    </div>        
</div> 

<script>
  var arr_flow = [];
  $("#btn_b").on("click", function(event){  
    $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function(key){
      arr_flow.push( $(this).val());
    }); 
    localStorage.setItem("arr_flow", arr_flow);
    location.href = "c.html";    
 })
</script>
```

**c.html**

```
<div data-role="page" id="page_c">        
    <div data-role="header" class="">
        <a href="a.html" data-ajax="false" id="btn_b" class="ui-btn ui-mini ui-btn-left">Page A</a> 
        <h3>Details</h3>
        <a href="b.html" data-ajax="false" id="btn_b" class="ui-btn ui-mini ui-btn-right">Page B</a>          
    </div>
    <div role="main" id="" class="ui-content"> 
        <p id="fr_title" style="display:none"><h3>Fruits</h3> </p>  
        <ul data-role="listview" id="list_fruit"></ul>  
        <p id="fl_title" style="display:none"><h3>Flowers</h3> </p>  
        <ul data-role="listview" id="list_flow"></ul>  
    </div>        
</div> 

<script>
  var list_fruit = "";
  var arr_fruit = localStorage.getItem("arr_fruit").split(",");

  var list_flow = "";
  var arr_flow = localStorage.getItem("arr_flow").split(",");

  $("#page_c").on("pageshow", function(event){  
    // Fruits
    $("#fr_title").show();
    $.each(arr_fruit, function(key, value){
        list_fruit += '<li>'+value+'</li>';
    });
    $("#list_fruit").html(list_fruit).trigger("create");
    $("#list_fruit").listview( "refresh" );   

    // Flowers   
   $("#fl_title").show();
   $.each(arr_flow, function(key, value){
       list_flow += '<li>'+value+'</li>';
   });
   $("#list_flow").html(list_flow).trigger("create");
   $("#list_flow").listview( "refresh" );    
 });
</script>
```

Comment: my app flow like this Page1 to Page4,page2 to Page4 ,page3 to Page4.when we call var gettingAllements it's remove previous  item list

Comment: You can write array data in file every time or combine old array and new array in one array.

Comment: Please look actual my problem is this Please if you any thing please guide me  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27798845/how-to-store-items-in-local-storage-in-jquerymoblie

Comment: ok... its sigle page app OR multiple page app..?

Comment: You can create two localStorage one for fruit and another for flowers and combine on c page both.